# Create WP_Query to search for posts by their categories or their parent/child categories

Tags: php, wp-query, database, query, mysql

Hello I am really sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find the exact solution I need. So here's the problem I want to create a search in my Wordpress page. Whenever a user submits the form I want to create a query to search for posts by their categories or their parents/child categories. Here's an example:

[image: Example]

So in MYSQL it would look something like this but I don't know how to do it in Wordpress with the help of WP_Query since I am new to this.

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE posts.category 
LIKE '%John Doe%' OR posts.sub_category LIKE '%John Doe%'
```

I haven't figured out how the tables are connected so probably a few JOIN operations need to be made here but I hope someone understands what I am asking.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably easier to use the in-built methods for WP_Query available than learning complex SQL queries...

Comment: That's what I am asking, I can't figure out the WP_Query

Comment: Sorry the way you phrased it I read it like you wanted SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_categories` first to get all the post categories to use in the form, then loop through them to display a multicheck input...

```
function hierarchical_category_inputs ($cat, $indent) {

    $cats = get_categories('hide_empty=false&orderby=name&order=ASC&parent='.$cat);
    $indent++;

    if ($cats) {
        foreach ($cats as $cat) {
           echo "<input type='checkbox' name='cat-".$cat->term_id."'";
           echo " style='margin-left: ".($indent*10)."px;'> ".$cat->name."<br>";
           hierarchical_category_inputs($cat->term_id, $indent);
        }
    }
}  

echo "<form method='post'>";
// 0 for all categories, -1 so first indent is 0
hierarchical_category_inputs(0,-1);
echo "<input type='hidden' name='custom_catsearch' value='yes'>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Search'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Then in the search part you would assemble the array of ticked categories to pass to `WP_Query`:

```
function custom_catsearch_output() {
    $cats = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // make sure the post key starts with cat-
        if (substr($key,0,4) == 'cat-') {
            // check for check of the checkbox
            if ($value == '1') {
                // get the cat id from after cat-
                $cats[] = substr($key,4,strlen($key));
            }
        }
    }

    $query = new WP_Query(array('cat' => $cats));

    print_r($query);
    // ... do something different with the results ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer I will try something like this but was hoping for something easier like 
$query = WP_Query(array('cat_name' => 'Blackburn'));
there's nothing similar to this?

Comment: you still need to use the cat ID but just get the term first: `$term = get_term_by('name','Blackburn','category'); $query = new WP_Query(array('cat' => $term->term_id);`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 4 ) );
```

Where 4 is the ID of the top-level category (Blackburn). This query will in clude subcats.

Reference - [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: But how do I find the id of the category I only know the name (e.g 'Blackburn') how do I know that's with the id of 4 or whatever?

Comment: This should probably be supplied by the form...